# The callback function used in SetWindowsHookEx is only called once

Tags: c++, dll-injection, setwindowshookex

I'm in the process of writing a dll-injected global keyboard hook but have run into a problem which I can't seem to get past. So far I have one program which is in charge of loading the dll and calling the SetWindowsHookEx, and ofcourse the dll to be injected.

The DLL looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {
    switch(Reason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                //fprintf(file, "DLL attach function called.\n");
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                //fprintf(file, "DLL detach function called.\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
                //fprintf(file, "DLL thread attach function called.\n");
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
                //fprintf(file, "DLL thread detach function called.\n");
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        FILE *file;
        string c;
        c += (char)wParam;
        fopen_s(&file, "c:\\temp2.txt", "a+");
        fprintf(file, c.c_str());
        fclose(file);
    }
    return(CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam));
}
```

The main program looks like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>

using namespace std;

void CheckForExit(HHOOK handle);

int main()
{

    /*
    * Load library in which we'll be hooking our functions.
    */
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary(L"dllinject.dll");
    if (dll == NULL) {
        printf("The DLL could not be found.n");
        //getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    /*
    * Get the address of the function inside the DLL.
    */
    HOOKPROC addr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(dll, "meconnect");
    if (addr == NULL) {
        printf("The function was not found.n");
        //getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    DWORD id = GetCurrentThreadId();
    HHOOK handle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, addr, dll, 0);

    if (handle == NULL) {
        printf("The KEYBOARD could not be hooked.n");
    }

    /*
    * Unhook the function.
    */
    system("pause");
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bigger question is "how can you tell?"  The callback function doesn't do anything so you can't possibly tell whether it is being called or not.  And no, don't set a breakpoint on it.  That of course kills your keyboard.  Not completely, Windows puts up with that for 5 seconds, then unceremoniously disables your hook because it is not responsive.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have some code there that simply opens a file, writes the key that has been pressed and then closes the file. However, when I open the file there's only a single new character for every time I run the hook.

Comment: So you overwrite what was in the file?  Your code snippet isn't exactly sufficient to provide us with a guess what's going wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant: It doesn't overwrite because the next time I inject the dll it will append the first character I write. I have updated the original post to include all the code.

Comment: Well, sure, that's a fail whale.  Apps cannot write files to the c:\ directory.  You might, at best, get a keyup message from your elevated instance of VS when you Alt+Tab to another app.  But then the show is over, the app with the focus simply can't write the file.  No error checking and no way to report an error, no way to tell why it doesn't work.  More possible failure modes on a 64-bit OS version, you can't inject a 64-bit process with a 32-bit DLL.